# Auto Complete formatting for TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been looking for a way to have a `TextBox` format while the user is inputting data.

I have made a hack that does what I want, but it is a bit finicky due things like when you accidentally press two keys at once which can screw with the `if` statements and when trying to delete the string via `Delete Key` by the user.

Anyway, that is not the issue and this is the code that I am using now:

Calling the methods from this class, The first method adds commas to the string and the second method checks if a comma is at the end when the user has finnished typing.

```
class BonusData
{
    public class DoDataTextBox
    {
        public static void AutoComplete(TextBox textBox, int counter)
        {
            if (textBox.Text.Length - counter == 3)
            {
                textBox.Text = textBox.Text + ",";
                textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
            }
            else if (textBox.Text.Length - counter == 7)
            {
                textBox.Text = textBox.Text + ",";
                textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
            }
            else if (textBox.Text.Length - counter == 11)
            {
                textBox.Text = textBox.Text + ",";
                textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
            }
        }

        public static void CheckLastCharacter(TextBox textBox)
        {
           if (textBox.Text.Length < 2) return;
           if (textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.Text.Length - 1) != ",") return;
           {
              textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBox.Text.Length - 1);
           }
        }
    }    
}
```

And the event handlers,

```
private void SecondMonthRowOne_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    if (IsText)
    {
        counter = 1;
    }
    BonusData.DoDataTextBox.AutoComplete((TextBox)sender, counter);
}


private void SecondMonthRowOne_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ToString() != String.Empty) return;
    IsText = true;
}


private void SecondMonthRowOne_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    BonusData.DoDataTextBox.CheckLastCharacter((TextBox)sender);
    IsText = false;
}
```

Which gives a result like this,

> 999,999,999

Like I said it works 98% of the time, but I was hoping there was another way to do this in WPF. I have searched far and wide, but I don't even know what something like this is called.

Comment: Is there a special reason you use a TextBox instead of an ComboBox with `IsEditable="True"`?

Comment: @lokusking, forgive my ignorance, but what is the advantage of that in this situation? Thanks

Comment: My bad. Misread your question. I initially thought you want some kind of predefined selection like in the old days Winforms' autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any outside addins I found this to work really well,

This will add a `Comma` every third character and allow users to delete characters one at a time.

The `TextBox` format will look like this,

> 999,999,999,999

[image]

The code,

```
    public class DoDataTextBox
    {
        public static void AutoCompleteStringBuild(TextBox textBox)
        {
            string endResult = null;

            string replace = Reverse(textBox.Text).Replace(",", "");
            int count = 1;
            char[] value = replace.ToCharArray();

            foreach (var car in value)
            {
                if (count % 3 == 0)
                {
                    endResult = String.Concat(endResult, car);
                    if (value.Length != count)
                    {
                        endResult = String.Concat(endResult, ",");
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    endResult = String.Concat(endResult, car);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (endResult == null) return;
            string textBoxResult = Reverse(endResult);
            textBox.Text = textBoxResult;
        }

        public static string Reverse(string stringVal)
        {
            char[] charArray = stringVal.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }

        public static void IsDeleteKey(TextBox textBox, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.SelectionStart = e.Key == Key.Delete ? 0 : textBox.Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

And the event handler,

```
private void TextBoxOne_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    BonusData.DoDataTextBox.AutoCompleteStringBuild((TextBox)sender);
    BonusData.DoDataTextBox.IsDeleteKey((TextBox)sender, e);
}
```

At present this is the best way I have found to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use "WPF TextBox AutoComplete" instead. It's a WPF attached behavior wrapped in a NuGet package.

You can simply add this package to your project by adding this using NuGet Package Manager for your WPF project.
This NuGet package is also open source, therefore you can customize it further to meet your needs/requirements.

The source code is hosted on this GitHub repo: https://github.com/Nimgoble/WPFTextBoxAutoComplete

NOTE: I haven't fully tested this WPF library against .NET 4.6. The library is compiled against .NET 4.5 as its target. But as far as I know, it's 100% compatible with WPF in .NET 4.6.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one question, what would the binding `IEnumerable<String>` look like , to get a string looking like this `999,999,999`

Comment: @KyloRen Binding to IEnumerable<String> can't be bound directly to a TextBox, because IEnumerable is a collection. Please consult this MSDN Library link for WPF Data Binding in .NET 4.5/4.6: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @KyloRen If you want to have the TextBox to have formatted with thousands separator, you can just format the data before displayed to the TextBox using String.Format. Please mark my answer as answer to your question about AutoComplete :)

Comment: I am sorry, but it has not answered my question yet. The documentation tells you to bind the `AutoCompleteItemsSource` to an `IEnumerable<String>`, which I am going to assume tells the `TextBox` how to behave or format the text. I am not sure what exactly I need to do to get that binding and it would be very helpful if you could update your answer to include a very small code sample to  show implementation of this type of control. Thanks